# Wordpress website content disappears on mobile / tablet

Tags: wordpress, mobile, plugins, tablet

I have this very weird problem – whenever I try to open a website I'm working on on mobile / tablet, all the content, logo, menus, widgets, everything [**disappears**](http://mobiletest.me/ipad_mini_emulator/#u=http://kristinaartgallery.ru).

The original theme I've bought [**is fine**](http://mobiletest.me/ipad_mini_emulator/#u=http://demo.virtuti.info/demonstrations/vt10/). I tried disabling all plugins, but it didn't help. What could possibly be the problem?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like on narrow screens (looking at the demo page), the content of the div with ID `ascensorFloor2` is shown (`ascensorFloor1` is shown on wider screens) .  Notice how the appearance of the demo page is very different on narrow screens.

Your `style.css` has this rule:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
#ascensorFloor1{
    display:none;
  }
}
```

at line 172, which is hiding your main content.

You don't seem to have a div with ID `ascensorFloor2` - you'll need to add it (how you'd do that will depend on the theme - without seeing the code it's not possible to tell).

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, so i'm writing here, In several cases i found out that too many CSS files can break the page display. You can try and use a plugins which agrogate all the CSS file to a single file, and see if it helps.

Comment: But I have only one CSS file - styles.css